# Raising Automation Events for JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, events, microsoft-ui-automation

I want to raise Automation Events that can be recorded for further use. Event should be raised when user interacts with JavaScript widget for example a button click.

I tried looking for this and found something similar - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720907(v=vs.85).aspx

but I cannot understand how can I use this with UI Automation API. Can someone point me to relevant to resources.